# How to plot data in LambertConformal projection

Tags: python, projection, holoviews, geoviews

I am trying to plot WRF output using Geoviews.  The WRF output files contain latitude and longitude information, which are both 2D arrays.

So what I'm currently trying is this:

1. Using the projection definition from Cartopy, calculate 1D x/y coordinates
2. Modify my `xr.Dataset` so that it has these 1D x/y coordinates
3. Create a `gv.Dataset` from this `xr.Dataset`, providing the WRF `crs` (which is Lambert Conformal, btw)
4. Plot a `gv.Image` from this `gv.Dataset`

The `xr.Dataset` looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (Time: 48, low_mid_high: 3, south_north: 210, west_east: 210)
Coordinates:
  * Time          (Time) datetime64[ns] 2016-08-22 2016-08-22T00:30:00 ...
  * low_mid_high  (low_mid_high) <U4 'low' 'mid' 'high'
  * south_north   (south_north) float64 -3.7e+06 -3.699e+06 -3.698e+06 ...
  * west_east     (west_east) float64 6.629e+06 6.627e+06 6.626e+06 ...
Data variables:
    cloudfrac     (low_mid_high, Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.533683 ...
```

and my code looks like this:

```
import geoviews as gv
import wrf
import xarray as xr

cldfrac = xr.open_dataset(FILENAME)

# create the ccrs object for the WRF projection
prj = wrf.get_cartopy(cldfrac._file_obj.ds)

# calculate x/y in Lambert Conformal proj,
# drop original XLONG/XLAT
cldfrac = ASSIGN_XY_COORDS(cldfrac)

geo_dims = ['south_north', 'west_east']
kdims = ['low_mid_high', 'south_north', 'west_east', 'Time']
vdims = ['cloudfrac']

dataset = gv.Dataset(cldfrac, kdims=kdims, vdims=vdims, crs=prj)
dataset.to(gv.Image, geo_dims, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I *do* get a result, however it is not in longitude/latitude projection, but in the original Lambert Conformal, meaning `south_north` and `west_east` are the y and x axes.

According to [the Geoviews website](http://geo.holoviews.org/Projections.html),

> both backends can use incoming data in any of the supported projections, via the crs parameter of most GeoViews objects.

**How can I have longitude/latitude as x and y axes in my Image?**

**EDIT:** I would prefer to use the Bokeh backend, if possible.  I don't care about the tick *labels*, actually, but the projection is wrong in the plot:  When the x/y axes represent lon/lat, as in the WebMercator projection, and using my LambertConformal data projection in the `gv.Image()` call, I expect the area of the Image to be non-square (left-right distance should be larger at the upper edge compared to the lower edge of the Image extents, in the Norther hemisphere).

Comment: Which plotting backend are you using? The bokeh backend currently doesn't support nice axis labels, but recently a MercatorTicker was added so please just follow [this issue](https://github.com/ioam/geoviews/issues/36). If you're working with the matplotlib backend, that supports a ``projection`` plot option, which determines what coordinate system the data actually gets rendered as.
    
In the notebook you can set that with this at the top of the cell.

        ``%%opts Image [projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()]``

Comment: I'd like to use Bokeh, see the updated question

Comment: While it is on the roadmap, bokeh does not yet support coordinate systems other than Mercator. [Here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/186)'s an issue about it, which seemingly hasn't been updated in years.

Comment: but what about the quote from the Geoviews website which I put into the question - is that wrong?

Comment: No, the quote is correct "both backends can use **incoming** data in any of the supported projections, via the crs parameter of most GeoViews objects." In other words your input data can be in any projection, but during display the bokeh backend will attempt to project it to Mercator so it can be displayed. The matplotlib backend on the other hand supports a ``projection`` plot option that lets you define what projection you want to display your data as.

Comment: But it's not even being projected to Mercator.  When I add coastlines, the extents of my data region (which is in Europe) is very small, somewhere in Alaska.  So it seems to me Bokeh is not *projecting* but rather just trying to interpret the coordinates as WebMercator coordinates.  It might help if I could specify 2D coordinate arrays (lat/lon), but I assume this also isn't supported (by Bokeh, or by Geoviews?)?

Comment: As an alternative, using the matplotlib backend would also work for now. However, I seem to have trouble with the 2D coordinate arrays ...